# Como pode verificar se número está em intervalo ser tão rápido?

Tags: python, desempenho

É sabido que com o módulo [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) é possível mensurar, em Python, o tempo de execução de trechos de códigos. Curioso, fui testar qual é o tempo que leva para se verificar se um determinado número está em um intervalo definido por `range`, tal como `x in range(A, B)`.

Para o teste, fiz:

```
$ python -m timeit -s '1000000000 in range(9999999999)'
```

Ou seja, defini o intervalo `[0, 9999999999[`, que é gigantesco, e verifiquei se o valor `1000000000` pertence a ele. O resultado obtido foi:

```
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00574 usec per loop
```

Que, além de resultar em um tempo bastante pequeno, se assemelha, por exemplo, ao tempo de verificar com um intervalo bem menor:

```
$ python -m timeit -s '1 in range(10)'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00577 usec per loop
```

Como isso é possível?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

De fato, considerando apenas o objeto do tipo `range`, o tempo para verificar se um determinado valor pertence ao intervalo é, na notação *big-O*, O(1), que significa que será constante independente do tamanho do espaço verificado, o que explica os tempos de ambos os testes serem iguais. E a explicação para isso é bem simples: matematicamente é muito fácil verificar se um número pertence a um intervalo.

## TL;DR

A solução mais básica que consigo imaginar para verificar se um número está em um determinado intervalo é percorrer todos os elementos deste intervalo, comparando um a um com o valor que estou verificando e, se caso encontrar um igual, retornar verdadeiro, caso contrário, falso.

```
def pertence(sequencia, valor):
    for item in sequencia:
        if item == valor:
            return True
    return False
```

Com certeza uma solução assim jamais seria O(1), na verdade seria O(n), o que poderia justificar tempos pequenos para intervalos pequenos, mas não justificaria o mesmo para intervalos grandes. Então como é possível?

Matematicamente, podemos dizer que o número `x` pertence ao intervalo `[A, B[` se, e somente se, `x` for maior ou igual a `A` e `x` for menor que `B`. Isto é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Toda essa mágica acontece no objeto `range` graças à implementação do método `__contains__`, que é implicitamente invocado através do operador `in`. E, além de verificar se o valor de `x` é maior ou igual a `A` e menor a `B`, quando definido o passo do intervalo, será necessário também verificar se o valor coincide com o passo. Por exemplo, se eu defino o objeto `range(0, 10, 2)`, estarei pegando os valores pares de 0 a 10 e, desta forma, o número 3 não pertencerá ao intervalo, mesmo que seja maior que 0 e menor que 10. Assim, a implementação em Python seria semelhante à:

```
class range:
    def __contains__(self, x):
        if not self.A <= x < self.B:
            return False
        if self.passo is not None:
            return (x - self.A) % self.passo == 0
        return True
```

Desta forma, a verificação não depende mais do tamanho do intervalo, mas sim de um número constante de operações, o que caracteriza ser uma solução O(1).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/UrbanDesertedClicks)</sup>

Porém, a classe `range` do Python pertence ao módulo `builtins`, que é implementada em C, não em Python. Ou seja, embora a lógica seja a mesma, o código que é executado, de fato, para verificar se o valor pertence ao intervalo é outro. A título de curiosidade, é possível acessar o [repositório oficial do CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) e verificar a implementação em C, mas especificamente entre as linhas 337 e 379:

```c
static int
range_contains_long(rangeobject *r, PyObject *ob)
{
    int cmp1, cmp2, cmp3;
    PyObject *tmp1 = NULL;
    PyObject *tmp2 = NULL;
    int result = -1;

    /* Check if the value can possibly be in the range. */

    cmp1 = PyObject_RichCompareBool(r->step, _PyLong_Zero, Py_GT);
    if (cmp1 == -1)
        goto end;
    if (cmp1 == 1) { /* positive steps: start <= ob < stop */
        cmp2 = PyObject_RichCompareBool(r->start, ob, Py_LE);
        cmp3 = PyObject_RichCompareBool(ob, r->stop, Py_LT);
    }
    else { /* negative steps: stop < ob <= start */
        cmp2 = PyObject_RichCompareBool(ob, r->start, Py_LE);
        cmp3 = PyObject_RichCompareBool(r->stop, ob, Py_LT);
    }

    if (cmp2 == -1 || cmp3 == -1) /* TypeError */
        goto end;
    if (cmp2 == 0 || cmp3 == 0) { /* ob outside of range */
        result = 0;
        goto end;
    }

    /* Check that the stride does not invalidate ob's membership. */
    tmp1 = PyNumber_Subtract(ob, r->start);
    if (tmp1 == NULL)
        goto end;
    tmp2 = PyNumber_Remainder(tmp1, r->step);
    if (tmp2 == NULL)
        goto end;
    /* result = ((int(ob) - start) % step) == 0 */
    result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(tmp2, _PyLong_Zero, Py_EQ);
  end:
    Py_XDECREF(tmp1);
    Py_XDECREF(tmp2);
    return result;
}
```

O parâmetro `r` representa o próprio objeto `range` e o parâmetro `ob` representa o valor a ser verificado. O objeto `r` possui os campos `start`, `stop` e `step` que representam o início, final e passo do intervalo. Embora seja uma implementação maior, a lógica é exatamente a apresentada anteriormente em Python.

Na implementação em C, também é possível verificar que o objeto `r` não é modificado em momento algum, o que implica que o gerador que é definido por `range` não será modificado ao verificar se o valor pertence ao intervalo. Por ser um gerador e, por definição, gerador poder ser iterado apenas uma vez, seria catastrófico se o operador `in` percorresse o `range`, pois o intervalo não teria mais utilidade depois disso. Perceba que estamos tratando aqui apenas do objeto `range` e suas peculiaridades, o que não implica em ser assim com todos os geradores do Python.

```
intervalo = range(10)

if 5 in intervalo:
    for i in intervalo:
        print(i)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TerribleInconsequentialInitialization)</sup>

Comment: Não entendi a operação matemática `(x - self.A) % self.passo == 0` no caso da variável `passo` conter valor. O que seria?

Comment: @gato por exemplo, `range(10, 20, 2)`, o valor de passo seria 2, assim, para verificar se 15 pertence, seria (15 - 10) % 2 == 0, falso, enquanto para 16 seria (16 - 10) % 2 == 0, verdadeiro.