# Para que serve a função range() em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Para que serve a função `range()` em Python? Qual a verdadeira utilidade dela? É apenas uma lista numérica?

Comment: Bom lembrar que a notação matematica do Range é: `range([start], stop[, step])`.

Comment: Isso não é notação matemática; acredito que você quis se referir à assinatura da função. E o correto seria `range(stop)` ou `range(start, stop[, step])`. Certo?

Comment: Relacionada: [Como pode verificar se número está em intervalo ser tão rápido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/291833/5878)

Comment: A notação dos intervalos. Na realidade vc tem razão...apesar de colchetes representar intervalos também, o mais comum em matemática é usar a reta dos reais.

Comment: Neste caso seria `α ∈ [start, stop[ ∀ α = start + k*step, k ∈ N` apenas. Na resposta pareceu que acabou misturando as coisas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O `range` é uma classe iterável. É um tanto semelhante a uma lista, mas com a diferença de que diferentemente de uma lista propriamente dita, os valores intermediários não são armazenados na memória, sendo então calculados a medida que ela for iterada com base no valor do `step` (que por padrão é 1). Dessa forma, um range com um elemento e um range com um milhão de elementos utilizam a mesma quantidade de memória, o que se traduz em economia de espaço e melhor desempenho.

Um exemplo de uso:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(i)
```

Este exemplo mostra os números de 1 até 9. O primeiro parâmetro, que se chama `start` é o primeiro número que está dentro do `range`. O segundo parâmetro, chamado de `stop` é o primeiro número que **não** está mais na sequência. O número 10 não aparece na sequência porque não está mais dentro do `range`, e portanto, isso vai de 1 até 9.

É possível também especificar-se o valor do `step` ao utilizar-se um terceiro parâmetro:

```
for i in range(1, 10, 2):
    print(i)
```

Isso daí vai mostrar os números 1, 3, 5, 7 e 9. Ou seja, pulando de 2 em 2.

Se apenas um único parâmetro for especificado, esse será o `stop` e o valor 0 será assumido para o `start`. Assim, `range(5)` corresponde aos números de 0 até 4.

O `range` também pode ser acessado em posições arbitrárias sem que valores intermediários precisem ser calculados (por exemplo, `range(1, 10)[3]`). O valor resultante (para índices positivos dentro do intervalo) é facilmente obtido por meio da fórmula `start + index * step`.

Answer (score 6):

Em Python 3, `range`, apesar de ser *usado* como uma função, inclusive nos exemplos iniciais de tutoriais em Python, não é uma função. É uma classe:

```
In [1]: teste = range(10)                                                                                          

In [2]: type(teste)                                                                                                
Out[2]: range

In [3]: type(range)                                                                                                
Out[3]: type

In [4]: isinstance(range, type)                                                                                    
Out[4]: True
```

`range` é uma classe e os objetos que são instâncias dessa classe, que podemos chamar de "ranges" tem todas as propriedades de Sequências Imutáveis em Python.

Em Python 2, `range` era uma função, que retornava uma lista (`list`), normal do Python:

```
Python 2.7.15 (default, Oct 15 2018, 15:26:09) 
...
In [1]: teste = range(10)

In [2]: type(teste)
Out[2]: list

In [3]: type(range)
Out[3]: builtin_function_or_method

In [4]: isinstance(range, type)
Out[4]: False
```

O que acontece é que em algum ponto se verificou que raríssimas, se é que alguma vez, ao ser necessário uma sequência numérica você vai precisar ter todos os números de uma sequência de uma vez na memória - ao percorrer a sequência, você vai usar um número de cada vez. Então ainda no Python 2 criaram o `xrange` que era essa classe especializada para "parecer uma função", cujo retorno "se comporta como uma lista", mas é na verdad euma sequência "virtual".

A chamada a range no Python 3 tampouco retorna um "iterador" em Python é algo diferente - é um objeto que fornece itens em sequência, e que pode, por exemplo, ser consumido pelo comando `for`, mas pode ser percorrido uma única vez. Se você tentar usar o mesmo iterador mais de uma vez, no segundo uso ele estará vazio.

Então o objeto "range", assim como as listas, tuplas e outras sequências é um "iterável": quer dizer - você pode construir iteradores com ele, quantas vezes quiser, e cada iterador vai gerar todos os elementos de forma independente. O comando `for` cria um iterador a partir de um iterável automaticamente, mas isso também pode ser feito de forma explícita com o built-in `iter`:

```
In [6]: print([i for i in teste])                                                                                  
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [7]: print([i for i in teste])                                                                                  
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [8]: t2 = iter(teste)                                                                                           

In [9]: print([i for i in t2])                                                                                     
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [10]: print([i for i in t2])                                                                                    
[]
```

E no fundo, apesar da class `range` estar definida em C, o equivalente em Python da mesma é muito simples. O que a chamada a range retorna é uma instância de uma classe equivalente a essa aqui:

```
class Range:
    def __init__(self, start, stop=None, step=1):
        if stop is None:
             stop = start
             start = 0
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        self.step = step

    def __len__(self):
         return (self.start - self.stop) // self.step

    def __getitem__(self, index):
         if index < 0: 
            index += len(self)
         result = self.start + self.step * index
         if index < 0 or result >= self.stop:
             raise IndexError
         return result

    def __iter__(self):
         i = 0
         while True:
              try:
                   yield self[i]
              except IndexError:
                   break
              i += 1
```

Pronto!

Todo o "segredo" para se calcular um número em uma posição do Range no momento que ele é requisitado, sem passar pelos anteriores, é a fórmula `result = self.start + self.step * index`.

Uma coisa interessante que fica clara nessa recriação é a parte do range que é bem intuitiva pra uso, mas pode dar dor de cabeça quando paramos para pensar: o  `range` do Python quando chamado com dois parâmetros usa o primeiro como início e o segundo como fim. Mas quando chamado apenas com um parâmetro, em vez de usar esse parâmetro como "início" e deixar o final indefinido, ele assume o ínicio como "0", o que faz bastante sentido, e coloca o único parâmetro como sendo o "fim".

Por isso é possível fazer `range(10)` para números de 0 a 10, e `range(5, 10)`, para números entre 5 e 10.

Nesta classe não está implementada  a lógica para permitir contagens regressivas com índices negativos - mas é só adicionar checagens distintas no `__getitem__` para quando o `self.step` for negativo - optei por deixar o código mais fácil de ntender. Por outro lado como também não checo os tipos dos parâmetros, essa classe funciona para números em ponto flutuante tão bem quanto para inteiros:

```
In [21]: a = Range(0, 2, 0.25)                                                                                     

In [22]: print([i for i in a])                                                                                     
[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75]
```

Vale a pena observar que ao implementar o método especial `__iter__` como um generator (isso é: com um `yield`), a classe passa a ser "iterável", como descrevi no começo. Em cada `for` que uma instância desta classe `Range` for usada, o Python vai chamar o `__iter__`, e ter um gerador, que vai contar todos os números disponíveis e "expirar".